# Prestashop 1.6 - Send a second email to the customer after order confirmation email

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I've search on some Prestashop forums and here on Stackoverflow but it seem that i can't find an answer for that question :

-Would it be possible to send a second email (based on a custom mail template), to the customer after the Order confirmation mail ?

The customer is buying a product, making payment, receive his order confirmation by email and then an other email would be sent to him saying a custom message.

I've looked into Email Alert Module but it doesn't look like it's meant to do that.

I'm on Prestashop v1.6

Thanks a lot for your help and time.

Comment: Do you have any programming skills? You will have to create a custom module for this.

Comment: I do but kinda new to prestashop!  I'll give a try to Singh suggestion. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by overriding the `PaymentModule` class.

The order confirmation mail is sent from the code inside `validateOrder()` function of `PaymentModule` class. You can simply add code to send the second email (custom email) after the order confirmation mail code.

The following code is responsible for sending Order Confirmation mail.

```
Mail::Send(
       (int)$order->id_lang,
       'order_conf',
       Mail::l('Order confirmation', (int)$order->id_lang),
       $data,
       $this->context->customer->email,
       $this->context->customer->firstname.' '.$this->context->customer->lastname,
       null,
       null,
       $file_attachement,
       null, _PS_MAIL_DIR_, false, (int)$order->id_shop
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Raghubendra Singh answer. Not sure it is the best approach.

You can do it by overriding the `PaymentModule` class (see `Mail::Send();`)

To create a custom email subjet, you have to modify :

```
app/Resources/translations/fr-FR/EmailsSubject.fr-FR.xlf
```

add you subject :

```
<trans-unit id="fca7e8d1c86db11246e429e40aa10c82" approved="yes">
        <source>Your new subject</source>
        <target xml:lang="fr">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</target>
        <note>Context:
File: classes/PaymentModule.php:844</note>
 </trans-unit>
```

You can also create a new email template :
add your file here :
(you can copy paste one of the template and modify it to your needs)

```
mail/fr/new-template.html
mail/fr/new-template.txt
```